# React native: Error "Unexpected identifier '_classCallCheck'.import call expects exactly one argument no stack no stack"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I need to change a project from 1 year ago. I keep getting the error shown in the picture. I have tried all the options that have been posted for other issues. I have modified version number "@babel/core" and "babel-preset-expo". I installed the package "metro-react-native-babel-preset". I replaced the node with newer and older versions. What could be the problem?

[image]

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/montserrat": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.6.2",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-constants": "~9.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-location": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.3.3",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "2.18.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.9",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.6.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "9.4.0",
    "victory-native": "^35.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Node version: v14.19.3

Comment: I modified babel.config.js file.


module.exports = {
  presets: [['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', {
    unstable_disableES6Transforms: true
  }]],
};